# Как с помощью jquery сделать прокрутку для субменю

Tags: jquery, списки, блок

Такая ситуация. Есть два блоки меню. первый блок работает нормально (кнопки вверх и вниз реагируют хорошо на всех пунктах). А вот второй блок кнопки вверх и вниз реагирует только в первом пункте. Во втором(цифра2 первый блок)  не хочет работать. Подскажите что сделать. Код:

https://jsfiddle.net/Tomak/r2hwg9rn/

```
function show(block)
{
    var menu = document.getElementById(block)
    if(menu.style.display == '') 
        menu.style.display = 'none'
    else 
        menu.style.display = ''
}

$('#list ul li ').click(function(){
        $('.hidding').eq($(this).index()).toggle().siblings('.hidding').hide()


});

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#up").click(function(event) {

    $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()+10);
});

$("#down").click(function(event) {
    $("#list").scrollTop($("#list").scrollTop()-10);
});

$(".up-submenu").click(function(event) {

    $(".list-submenu").scrollTop(
        $(".list-submenu").scrollTop()+10);
});

$(".down-submenu").click(function(event) {
    $(".list-submenu").scrollTop(
        $(".list-submenu").scrollTop()-10);
});

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]